# Could "rails s -e p" and "rails s -e production" be used interchangeably?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems like I just realized today that they are not the same since it creates different outcomes, I can run `rails s -e production` and got my app works normally but got an error when I used `rails s -e p` I always thought that these two can be used interchangeably like `rails s` and `rails server` Could anyone tell me the difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't, because using `-e` switch, you pass name of the environment explicity. You could define custom environment named `p` other than `production` and run it with `rails s -e p`.